# Can I create a custom resolution (modeline) using restricted nvidia graphics driver?

Tags: ubuntu, modeline

I'd like to create a custom modeline/resolution for the DVI output of my 8400GS card in my Ubuntu 9.04 system, using the nvidia restricted driver.

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, how do I do it?  xorg.conf?  Or some secret nvidia database?

I ask because I spent man-days trying to make a custom resolution work with a component video output under 8.04 only to find out that for some unfathomable reason it is simply not supported (it's trivial in Windows with the same hardware).

Comment: It's been a decade since I did that (ran a fixed frequency high res sun monitor), and while thing have changed, I'd think it can be done. Google it?

Comment: Googling hasn't helped yet.  Occasionally see people that want something similar but no definitive answers either way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [it can be done](http://sathyasays.com/2008/10/26/how-to-tackle-screen-resolution-problems-in-linux/).